# How to properly set onDeleteAssociationPolicy?

Tags: alfresco

I have custom content type, which has target association. I want to set up a policy, which perform some action, when association is removed. I wrote this policy as I usualy write another policies, but in some reason it does not work. My init() in OnDeleteAssociationPolicy implementation looks like this:

```
policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
    QNAME,
    PublishModel.pubWebContent,
    new JavaBehaviour(this, QNAME.toPrefixString(), NotificationFrequency.EVERY_EVENT)
);
```

PublishModel.pubWebContent is qname of my custom content type. Now I think when onDeleteAssociation() is called, I should check which association was deleted. But this method is never called after remove association :(. How to set this policy? Should I provide PublishModel.pubMyAssociation instead of PublishModel.pubWebContent (that does not work too)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled a little bit and found working [piece of code](https://code.google.com/p/fme-alfresco-extensions/source/browse/branches/pre-4.x/fme+extended+Datalist+-+Repository/src/java/de/fme/alfresco/repo/policy/DataListItemPolicies.java?r=153), which helped me to get that policy worked. The point is to use **bindAssociationBehavior** instead of bindClassBehavior method. So working binging should look like this:

```
policyComponent.bindAssociationBehaviour(
    QNAME,
    PublishModel.pubWebContent,
    PublishModel.pubGroupAssociation,
    onDeleteAssociation
);
```